# How do I protect a directory in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, authorization

What would be the simplest way of protecting a directory in asp.net mvc?

Currently I have a folder of misc files which belong to numerous users of the site. Ideally I do not want one user being able to type the URL to one of these documents in a browser and have access to it. These files should only be downloadable through a controller action that will authorise the download by verifying the users credentials and then returning a file.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to these is usually to have that directory exist outside of the web's ability to access.  For example, instead of storing them at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\docs, just store them at C:\inetpub\docs.

Just make sure your controller has read / ?write? privileges.

This posed the best solution for me when I was adding / removing folders, as my host restricted my ability to turn the file monitor off.  And it turns out that deleting a sub-folder of an application causes an app pool recycle >_<

Comment: Thanks Guys,
I shall give this approach a go. Just hope my host allows me to have read / write access outside public_html

Answer (score 7):

Store the files in app data and have your controller action read the file and render it as a FileResult.  That way the files are never exposed directly.

Comment: Just make sure that the AuthorizeAttribute is on the action if you are using forms based authentication